# Difference between type 34 and type 50 custom actions?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.5

My MSI installer needs to run `[SystemFolder]SCHTASKS.EXE`. Is there any practical difference in configuring the `CustomAction` as a type 34 or type 50?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are some huge differences:

- type 34 sets a working directory for your EXE, type 50 doesn't
- type 34 needs a folder path in Source column, type 50 needs the full EXE path
- type 34 needs the EXE filename and its command line arguments in Target column, type 50 needs only the EXE command line arguments

For your scenario I recommend type 34.